# Binary tree node value maximization

Tags: graphs, search-algorithms, dynamic-programming, binary-trees

Given a binary tree, construct the set of nodes whose sum is maximum subject to the restriction: if a node is included, its parent and children must be excluded, but grandchildren, etc. may be included.

My intuition tells me dynamic programming (and possibly two-coloring) should be involved, but not sure where to start. Could you please offer me a hint?

Comment: See the answer [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/41817/4911).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is known as Independent Set (and not two-coloring). Your intuition is quite correct though.

As a hint, I'd like to offer the following definitions:

Let $n$ be a node of the binary tree. Let $P(n)$ be the maximum profit that can be attained from the subtree rooted at $n$ given that $n$ itself may *not* be included. Similarly, let $Q(n)$ be the maximum profit that can be attained from the subtree rooted at $n$ given that $n$ itself may be included.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately my "reputation" does not allow me to upvote.

Comment: Learnt quite a bit. Is there a way to modify the algorithm to identify the nodes participating in the maximum sum?